# Add existing RealmObject to RealmList asychronously

Tags: android, realm

No code for this one, as it's a general question. Is it possible, on Android, to add a `RealmObject` subclass instance, that is still managed by Realm, to a `RealmList` via `executeTransactionAsync()`?

An example: class A is a `RealmObject` subclass. On the main thread I pull an instance of A from Realm, and need to add it to another `RealmList` that is managed by Realm. I would like to do so in an asynchronous transaction started by the same main thread.

I am getting `IllegalStateException` with a message of "Cannot copy an object from another Realm instance." Is this expected?

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous transaction runs on a background thread, and you can't pass managed Realm, RealmResults and RealmObject between threads. You can pass primary key though.

```
MyClass myClass = realm.where(MyClass.class).findFirst();
final long id = myClass.getId();
realm.executeTransactionAsync((bgRealm) -> {
    MyClass bgClass = bgRealm.where(MyClass.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
    B b = bgRealm.where(B.class).equalTo("id", bId).findFirst();
    b.getList().add(bgClass);
});
```

---

This will probably change a bit when `thread-safe reference` is added, but that's not available yet.